# SQL: Choose highest value per column

Tags: sql

I am supposed to find the most common genre per country, and the total amount of movies that country makes. My output is just a query away from being correct (se example)

```
select count(c.filmid) as amountMovies, c.country as country, avg(r.rank) as avg rank, fgt.genre
from filmcountry c
full join filmrating r on c.filmid = r.filmid
left join (
select count(co.filmid) as no, co.country, fg.genre from filmcountry co 
full join filmgenre fg on co.filmid = fg.filmid
group by co.country, fg.genre
order by co.country, no desc)
fgt on c.country = fgt.country 
group by c.country, fgt.genre 
order by c.country;
```

As you can see, I am able to see the amount of movies, country, av rang and there most famous genre (Adventure), but I am not able to only select the first line. Same with Albania.

I want it to be like this:

```
 amountMovies  |            country             |        avg rank        |    genre    
--------+--------------------------------+--------------------+-------------
     29 | Afghanistan                    | 3.9962963086587413 | Adventure

  874 | Albania                        |  7.149999976158142 | Music
```

This is what I am getting! See example below-->

```
  amountMovies  |            country             |        avg rank        |    genre    
--------+--------------------------------+--------------------+-------------
     29 | Afghanistan                    | 3.9962963086587413 | Adventure
     29 | Afghanistan                    | 3.9962963086587413 | Music
     29 | Afghanistan                    | 3.9962963086587413 | Short
     29 | Afghanistan                    | 3.9962963086587413 | Action
     29 | Afghanistan                    | 3.9962963086587413 | Biography
     29 | Afghanistan                    | 3.9962963086587413 | Documentary
     29 | Afghanistan                    | 3.9962963086587413 | War
     29 | Afghanistan                    | 3.9962963086587413 | Drama
     29 | Afghanistan                    | 3.9962963086587413 | 
    874 | Albania                        |  7.149999976158142 | Music
    874 | Albania                        |  7.149999976158142 | Documentary
    874 | Albania                        |  7.149999976158142 | Drama
    874 | Albania                        |  7.149999976158142 | 
    874 | Albania                        |  7.149999976158142 | Family
    874 | Albania                        |  7.149999976158142 | Thriller
```

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: What to do if a country has two top genres with exactly the same amount of movies?

Comment: It is hard to fix the query without actually seeing the data. It would be helpful if you could provide a minimal dataset from the concerned tables, along with the corresponding expected result.

Comment: You don't have a country table? And why do you have the table filmrating in the query? It  has nothing to do with the number of movies and genres in a country.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: maybe they want the highest ranking genre rather than the genre with most movies...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per country you want to get the total movie count and the genre(s) with the highest movie count in the country.

Count the movies per country and genre and rank the genres per country by count. Only keep the best ranked genre(s) per country. That's about it. Now either just display the rows or aggregate by country in order to only get one result row per country showing the genres in a list.

```
select 
  country,
  string_agg(genre, ',') as top_genres,
  any_value(movie_count) as country_movie_count
from
(
  select 
    fc.country,
    fg.genre, 
    rank() over (partition by fc.country order by count(*) desc) as genre_rnk,
    sum(count(*)) over (partition by fc.country) as movie_count
  from filmcountry fc
  join filmgenre fg using (filmid)
  group by fc.country, fg.genre
)
where genre_rnk = 1
group by country;
```